# Mongodb - 16Mb limit with aggregation during unwind

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got a collection on which I want to perform an aggregation. Weeks ago, everything worked perfectly, and since I've added some documents (with the same schema). However, when I try to aggregate my collection, I have the 16Mb limit of a BSON document exception that is thrown.

The most surprising is that I tried to identify when the limit is reached in the aggregation, and it is reached at the first step, where I simply unwind part of the document.

My question is then, how a stored document (which is by nature of size less than 16Mb) can become more than 16Mb after unwinding ? Note that the exception is thrown when I try to insert the resulting cursor into another collection with the InsertBatch method. I tried also to enumerate in the cursor but I have the same exception, the same if I try to access the first document.

[Edit]: I'm using version 2.6.1 of MongoDB and version 1.9.2 of the C# driver

[Edit]: The documents I use are similar to

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ff90e8dcb48a09f090f291"),
    "Val1" : 10
    "Val2" : true,
    "Mesure" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53ff90e8dcb48a09f090f284"),
        "Calibration" : {
            "CalibrationDate" : ISODate("2014-08-28T16:29:59.335-04:00"),
            "Expected" : [ 
                {
                    "Bin" : 12,
                    "PositionCalibrated" : 0,
                    "PositionExpected" : 0,
                    "PositionMax" : 0,
                    "PositionMin" : 0,
                    "PositionStd" : 0,
                    "PositionTab" : [ 
                        0, 
                        0, 
                        0
                    ],
                    "PositionTolerance" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "Bin" : 11,
                    "PositionCalibrated" : 406.113044449032,
                    "PositionExpected" : 401.1,
                    "PositionMax" : 406.113044449032,
                    "PositionMin" : 406.113044449032,
                    "PositionStd" : 5.684341886080802e-014,
                    "PositionTab" : [ 
                        406.113044449032, 
                        406.113044449032, 
                        406.113044449032
                    ],
                    "PositionTolerance" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "Bin" : 7,
                    "PositionCalibrated" : 454.9231746931026,
                    "PositionExpected" : 431.1,
                    "PositionMax" : 454.9231746931027,
                    "PositionMin" : 454.9231746931027,
                    "PositionStd" : 5.684341886080802e-014,
                    "PositionTab" : [ 
                        454.9231746931027, 
                        454.9231746931027, 
                        454.9231746931027
                    ],
                    "PositionTolerance" : 1
                }
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ff9143dcb48a09f090f2ae")
        }
    },
    "PositionMeasured" : 407.23645821
}
```

I use the aggregation pipeline with the C# driver. I want to do several aggregation steps (unwind, sort, group, project etc...) but the first step is to unwind those elements. The code used is as follow :

```
var UnwindCalib = new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$Mesure.Calibration.Expected");
var pipeline = new[] { UnwindCalib };
var args = new AggregateArgs();
args.Pipeline = pipeline;
args.AllowDiskUse = true;
var result = myCollection.Aggregate(args);
resultsCollection.InsertBatch(result); <----- I've got an error here.
```

The goal after unwinding is to match an expected item in the calibration to the current item.

Comment: To calculate the size of output after unwinding, you can approximate it to be `size of single doc * total number of elements in the unwinded array`.

Comment: What aggregation query are you using? Isn't it simply unwinding multiple documents?

Comment: Please include the pipeline and a description of how you know which pipeline stage is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Mongo DB agggregate operation will return a cursor only if you pass a `cursor:{}` argument to it. The *cursor* aggregation option is documented [here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-initial-batch-size) Working with cursors returned by aggregate operations using the C# driver is discussed in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-csharp/JuuFpmK2rOA)

Also, if your intention at the first stage is to store the aggregation result to another collection you should use `{$out:[collection_name]}` as the last stage in your aggregation pipeline. The mongodb documentation for the *$out* operator can be found [here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) This operator circumvents the 16MB document size limit since it's an in-DB operation and is handled accordingly by Mongo DB.

Comment: I know that, but I dont know how to do the same with the C# driver...and havent found it yet, and in fact the $out option is not available in the current version of the driver. For the cursor one, I dont know

Comment: Well, my fault, the $out aggregation command is now available since version 1.9 of the driver (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-800?jql=text%20~%20%22%24out%22). Mea cupla.

Comment: @GuillaumeA I have edited my answer to provide a thread which discusses the use of aggregation cursors in C#. The answer is addresses your question as is...you just didn't indicate the options you have thought about already. Hence, I don't agree with the down-vote.

Comment: I'll check your thread. Sorry for the down-vote, it was a mistake ans I was mot allowed tout change it :( I'll try mater, maybe it was too close un time from my wrong manipulation...